# How do I run insert scripts in one service in spring, mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, execute, multiple-insert

I am using Sprig 4.2xx / Mybatis/ MariaDB.
I have Mybatis insert query.

```
<insert id="insertSideAttRel" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
    <foreach collection="sideAttList" item="item" index="index" >  
        INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES
            (${menuSeq}, #{item}, #{storeCode}, NOW(), #{sessionId});
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

this makes like this examples,

```
 INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES
            (378209, '01', '2018000199', NOW(), 'snkim');

        INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES
            (378209, '02', '2018000199', NOW(), 'snkim');

        INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES
            (378209, '03', '2018000199', NOW(), 'snkim');
```

and the error is as follow.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date' at line 6
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1203) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.PreparedStatementSpy.execute(PreparedStatementSpy.java:418) ~[log4jdbc-remix-0.2.7.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:58) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.execute(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:41) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:66) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:45) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:108) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:75) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:145) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:134) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355) [mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.insert(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:237) [mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:79) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40) [mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.insertSideAttRel(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.core.web.interceptor.aspect.LoggingAspect.daoAround(LoggingAspect.java:61) [framework-core-web-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.insertSideAttRel(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.kcl.emo.web.menu.service.MenuService.updateSideMenuAttRel(MenuService.java:503) [classes/:na]
    at com.kcl.emo.web.menu.service.MenuService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$68bc2d76.invoke() [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.core.web.interceptor.aspect.LoggingAspect.serviceAround(LoggingAspect.java:45) [framework-core-web-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.emo.web.menu.service.MenuService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4066e173.updateSideMenuAttRel() [classes/:na]
    at com.kcl.emo.web.menu.controller.MenuController.updateSideMenuAttRel(MenuController.java:506) [classes/:na]
    at com.kcl.emo.web.menu.controller.MenuController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e163ff46.invoke() [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64) [spring-security-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.emo.comm.vo.RequestParamAspect.controllerAround(RequestParamAspect.java:62) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.core.web.interceptor.aspect.LoggingAspect.controllerAround(LoggingAspect.java:37) [framework-core-web-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.emo.web.menu.controller.MenuController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b037db1.updateSideMenuAttRel() [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:51) [logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.kcl.core.security.access.interceptor.EzSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(EzSecurityInterceptor.java:39) [framework-core-security-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.53]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
2018-12-24 14:34:39,070 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 /admin/servlet/menu/updateSideMenuAttRel.emo [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] jdbc.sqlonly[n.s.l.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator][exceptionOccured:125] -  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(null:-1)
```

But this queries cannot be executed in Spring.
I think Spring executes queries by it's statement not by scrpits.

That queries are what I want to excute. Any answers for me, Thanks! and Merry Christmas!

====================================================================

The way I resolve this problem is as follwed...

```
param. 
Map<String,Object> sideAttList : sideAttList=[01, 02]

mybatis.xml.
<insert id="insertSideAttRel" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
        INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES
        <foreach collection="sideAttList" item="item" index="index" separator=",">  
            (${menuSeq}, #{item}, #{storeCode}, NOW(), #{sessionId})
        </foreach>
    </insert>

resoulutions.
INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES

            (378209, '01', '2018000199', NOW(), 'snkim')
         ,   
            (378209, '02', '2018000199', NOW(), 'snkim')
```

Comment: Can you post exception stacktrace if any?

Comment: @CoderCroc thanks for watching, I edited my answer

Comment: Not very sure about the script execution by spring. But if your goal is to insert multiple rows at one go, you can use batch execution which will insert multiple rows in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL syntax error you are getting because internally prepared statement is executing all the insert SQL statements as a single query, a prepared statement can only execute single query at a time.

With existing MySQL foreach, you need to add separator,

```
<insert id="insertSideAttRel" parameterType="java.util.HashMap"  >
    <foreach collection="sideAttList" item="item" index="index" separator=";">  
        INSERT INTO side_att_rel
            (menu_seq, side_att_class_code, store_code, reg_date, reg_name)
        VALUES
            (${menuSeq}, #{item}, #{storeCode}, NOW(), #{sessionId}) <!-- ; is removed -->
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Currently the problem is your all insert statements are joined with `,` and whole script is wrapped with brackets `()` before execution. So, right now the final query will be,

```
(
  INSERTQuery1,
  INSERTQuery2,
  INSERTQuery3,
  //...
)
```

This end up in syntax error, when we add separator it will become,

```
(
  INSERTQuery1;
  INSERTQuery2;
  INSERTQuery3;
  //...
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Just one more question, If I don't use batch execution, Is there any way to handle this using MySQL <foreach>?

Comment: @henrykim you can add separator, see my answer.

Comment: Thaaaaanks! I am sure you can get Santa's gift tomorrow. Still Mybatis foreach's way isn't working for me. I will try batch execution. Thank you so much!!